# Horizontal Scrolling With two divs

Tags: html, css

What i want to do is to scroll my web page in two direction that is leftPanel in left to right direction while rightPanel in right to left direction but the header remain fixed in its postion. But i am stuck some where.

### here is my code:

### HTML File-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Page </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/default.css'>
    </head>
    <body class='aboutUsBody'>
        <div id='header'></div>
        <div id='mainPanel'>
            <div id='leftPanel'></div>
            <div id='rightPanel'></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

### CSS File-

```
html{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: #bad960;
}

#mainPanel{
    height: 90%;
    display: inline;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#leftPanel{
    float: left;
    margin-left: -200px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width:100 %;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#rightPanel{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

### please look at the image for further explaination:

[image]

at the page load scroll will be at center and the two divs positioned accordingly, when i scroll up the leftPanel scrolls from left to right and when i scroll down its rightPanel move from right to left.
What should i do ??

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is quite awkward to achieve because the scrollable divs must have a known width otherwise it is really difficult to control the line-wrap to act in your favour, but if you have a fairly static design to aim for it can work quite well.

You have quite a few strange things in your code that don't seem to be doing anything useful but it could be due to me misunderstanding what you are aiming for, also, some javascript might be essential for this, at least to get the left panel to start scrolled all the way to the right.

Here is my working css for something like what you are trying to do:

```
html{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: #bad960;
}

#mainPanel{
    height: 90%;
}
#leftPanel{
float: left;
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#rightPanel{
    float: left;
    color: red;
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.horizScroll{
    width: 800px;    
}
#leftPanel .horizScroll{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtg5yepd/)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but what i want is a single horizontal scroll for both of the Panels and at the page load it stays in center and then user can scroll it either to left or right.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research and i had achieved it by adding a little jquery.

My code is :

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Page </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/default.css'>
        <script src="./jQuery.1.10.0.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mainPanel").scrollLeft(document.body.clientWidth*0.25);
            $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
            if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {

            }
            else {

            }
});
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class='aboutUsBody'>
        <div id='header'></div>
        <div id='mainPanel'>
            <div id='panelOne' class='panel'></div>
            <div id='panelTwo' class='panel'></div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

### CSS file

```
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: #bad960;
    position: fixed;
}

#mainPanel{
    top:10%;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display: block;
    background: yellow;

}
#panelOne{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;

}
#panelTwo{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    background: aqua;

}
```

and here its fiddle:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qopy8vx/)